# What snake is this?

Tags: species-identification, snake

[image: http://imgur.com/a/0dfCW]

Just caught this snake today and he was really aggressive...tried to bite me but luckily I managed to kill him and I wonder what type of snake is this. If someone knows, help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Edit: the snake was found in Italy near Parma

Comment: It would be useful if you could update the question to include where the snake was found.

Comment: A zoom on the head might be useful. Scale patterns are used to identify snakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a [Balkan Whip Snake](http://en.balcanica.info/2-10197) (Hierophis gemonensis (syn. Coluber gemonensis)):

[image]

More images:

- [Reptiles of Crete](http://jbmclaren0.tripod.com/NED11A5JohnMcLaren/balkan.html)
- [Reptile Database](http://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Hierophis&species=gemonensis)
- [Balcanica.info](http://en.balcanica.info/1-42-1)
- [Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Benny_Trapp_Hierophis_gemonensis.jpg)

According to [iNaturalist.org](http://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/29917-Hierophis-gemonensis):

> The Balkan whip snake is a slender snake with smooth scales usually under a metre (yard) long but exceptionally reaching 130 cm (50 ins). The head is fairly distinct from the body and has prominent eyes with round pupils. The head and front of the body are olive-grey or yellowish-brown with dark spots separated by paler areas which may form irregular bars. There are often small white specks on some of the scales. Further back the dark spots are usually arranged in longitudinal lines giving a striped effect.

This snake is not endangered (["Least Concern"](http://www.iucnredlist.org/details/61510/0)) but there was no need to kill it, since it is non-venomous; you were certainly not "lucky" to kill this harmless animal.

Comment: I dont think so, iaork. The speckes of the snake in the question are black sploches on a light green background. The snake you have pictured has speckles which are more angular. Also, they are not in the same pattern as the ones in griffinwish's picture.They aren' on the same light green backgrown either. The colors of the individuals in many snake species  can vary a lot, I don't think that is the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the location and general shape/pattern I would say [Green whip snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_whip_snake). The genus is the same as the one from the previous answer, but these inhabit the mentioned location. They can vary in the coloration from very patterned, as in the photo, to completely black.

[image]

[image: Western subspecies - *Hierophis viridiflavus carbonarius*]

Non venomous, not dangerous and usually only aggressive when provoked, but they do bite...

edit1: Don't kill snakes...